# combn dataframe R for 1 variable only

Tags: r, combinations, combn

I have a data.frame with the following structure:

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
 y  n  y  n  n  y
 n  n  y  n  n  y
 y  y  y  y  y  n
```

I want to make combinations **combn()** but using only for only 1 of the variable, I mean, gettingthis result:

```
x1 x2
x1 x3
x1 x4
x1 x5
x1 x6
```

Instead of: (there are too many varibales that I dont need, and I want to choose the x[i])

```
x1 x2
...
x2 x1
x2 x2
...
x6 x5
```

Thank you

Comment: Maybe `reshape2::melt(your_data, id.vars = "x1")`? I'm a bit confused about what you want to happen to your `y` and `n` values

Comment: Or perhaps just `cbind(names(your_df)[1], names(your_df)[-1])`?

Comment: Theyre just a example of what is inside of each x[i]

Comment: Right, but they are completely absent in your output. Do you want them discarded like that? If so, why are they in your question at all? Does it matter that you have a data frame or is it just the vector of names that you want to work with?

Comment: They do matter, but i Want to create a new df with only 2 of those vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Using this data

```
your_data = structure(list(x1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("n", 
"y"), class = "factor"), x2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("n", 
"y"), class = "factor"), x3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "y", class = "factor"), 
    x4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("n", "y"), class = "factor"), 
    x5 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("n", "y"), class = "factor"), 
    x6 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("n", "y"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x1", 
"x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

This matches the output you ask for:

```
cbind(names(your_data)[1], names(your_data)[-1])
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "x1" "x2"
# [2,] "x1" "x3"
# [3,] "x1" "x4"
# [4,] "x1" "x5"
# [5,] "x1" "x6"
```

It's a matrix, but you could easily convert to data frame with `as.data.frame`. You could also functionalize it based on the column number you want in the first position.

```
single_combn = function(vec, pos) {
    cbind(vec[pos], vec[-pos])
}
```

Use example:

```
single_combn(names(your_data), 1)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "x1" "x2"
# [2,] "x1" "x3"
# [3,] "x1" "x4"
# [4,] "x1" "x5"
# [5,] "x1" "x6"

single_combn(names(your_data), 3)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "x3" "x1"
# [2,] "x3" "x2"
# [3,] "x3" "x4"
# [4,] "x3" "x5"
# [5,] "x3" "x6"
```